# Bootstrap - Push whole row to top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my `lg` layout:

```
------------------------------------------------
|     3(xs4)|    3(xs4)|    3(xs4)|   3(12xs)  |
------------------------------------------------
```

This is my `xs` layout:

```
------------------------------------------------
|     4         |      4        |     4        |
------------------------------------------------   
|                  12                          |
------------------------------------------------
```

My html so far (without push and pull):

```
           <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4  text-center">

                            </div> 
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4  text-center">

                            </div> 
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4  text-center">

                            </div> 
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12  text-left">


                            </div>   

                       </div
```

What i need:

The last column of the `lg` layout has to be on top in the `xs` layout. 
When i use `push` and `pull` i can only change the position IN the row. The columns are not jumping automatically into next/previous row.

My desired result:

```
------------------------------------------------
|                  12                          |
------------------------------------------------
|     4         |      4        |     4        |
------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order of your elements in the HTML so that your `col-*-12` is first. Then you can use `push` and `pull` like this:

```css
/* For demo only... */
[class*="col-"] {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-push-9 text-left">
    12
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 col-sm-pull-3  text-center">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 col-sm-pull-3  text-center">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 col-sm-pull-3  text-center">
    4
  </div>
</div>
```

Without changing the order of the elements you can not achieve your desired layout with `push` and `pull`.